# "Compile error in module" occurs when any macro is run [Excel VBA]

Tags: excel, vba

I encountered the following error when attempting to run any macro in a previously-working workbook:

[image: Error encountered when macro is run]

It had been working the previous day prior to doing a final save-and-close at the end of the day after doing various VBA development, however when opening the workbook up this morning I was greeted with the aforementioned error. The quoted module in the error is a function performed in a Workbook_Open action.

I was still able to access the VBA editor and try to do some debugging, which was essentially commenting out parts of the quoted module until the error wouldn't show up anymore. Despite these efforts, the error continued showing up any time a new macro was attempted to be run.

It appears that this error is a result of some sort of file corruption that occurred and didn't manifest itself until the file was closed and then re-opened the next day. I was able to restore an auto-backed-up version from earlier the previous morning which opened perfectly fine without errors (missing about 4 hours of work, but better than losing the file completely). This restored file had macros functioning properly that the seemingly corrupted file was giving the compile error for (and these macros had not been modified in the 4 hours between file versions). This further confirms for me that this was not a change in code but in some sort of corruption of VBA code structure.

Has anybody else encountered this issue and know where to even start to look to recover the most recent file?

Answer (score 0):

While re-building the modules in the restored file that I had created in the corrupted version, I realized that in the previous day I had copied-and-pasted (using Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V) some code from a Sheet Object to a Module (I originally wanted the code to be able to migrate with the sheet when the sheet was exported, then changed my mind and wanted to have the code accessible to other sheets in the workbook while sacrificing the ability to bring code with an exported sheet).

When I performed the copy-and-paste action within the VBA editor, the macros in the selection list (when assigning a macro to a shape object) had the macros listed with the module name as a "Parent" sub-address (similar to how the Sheet Object subs show up in the sheet as "Sheet1.ExampleSub"). My subs were shown as "NewModule.ExampleSub", which at the time I thought nothing of except for it just being kind of odd/quirky but not a big deal. After assigning these macros to various shape objects, they tested fine and I carried on with my work. I must not have closed and reopened the workbook at any point after that which is why I didn't encounter any compile errors until the following day.

This is the only thing I can think of that would have caused the workbook structure errors I was getting, and now that I've recreated the modules in the restored file version, the macros are working properly and the file closes and reopens without errors or issue. I am still unsure about why doing a Ctrl-A selection of code in a Sheet Object and copy-pasting in a Module would break the workbook structure, but it seems to have done so in this case.